# Integrating for a solution in terms of an natural logarithm

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

Evaluating the following integral:
$$\int_1^2 \frac2{1-3x}\  dx$$

why do you have to take the factor of $-2/3$ out when evaluating the integral?

Comment: Do you know substitution?

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_1^2\frac{2}{1-3x}\,dx=-2\int_1^2\int\frac{dx}{3x-1}=-\frac{2}{3}\int_1^2\frac{3\,dx}{3x-1}=-\frac{2}{3}\int_1^2\int\frac{d(3x-1)}{3x-1}$

Comment: since $$\int \frac{1}{x-a}dx=\ln|x-a|+C$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you didn't take that factor out, you would be tempted to try:
$$\int_1^2 \frac 2{1-3x} dx = -\frac{2}{3}\ln(1-3x)\bigg|_1^2 = -\frac 23\left[\ln(-5) - \ln(-1)\right]$$
But this can't be... because $\ln(u)$ is undefined for $u\leq 0$.

If you remove this factor:
$$\int_1^2 \frac 2{1-3x}\ dx = -\frac 23\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x - \frac13}\ dx = -\frac 23 \left[\ln\left(\frac 53\right) - \ln\left(\frac 23\right)\right] = \frac 23 \ln\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)$$

Comment: Shouldn't be the first result $-\frac 23[\ln (-5)-\ln (-2)]$ ? Which using the property of logs can in fact be rewritten as $\frac 23 \ln (\frac 25)$

Comment: The anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{t}$ is $\ln\color{red}{|t|}$, so no problem with negative.

Answer (score 2):

Using the substitution method, let $u=1-3x$. Then differentiate $u$ with respect to $x$ to get $dx = -\frac{1}{3} du$. Substitute away $dx$ and $1-3x$ in your integral to obtain $$-\frac{2}{3} \int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{u}\,du.$$

Then replace your upper and lower limits of $x$ with that of $u$ to obtain $$-\frac{2}{3} \int_{-2}^{-5} \frac{1}{u}\,du,$$

and then take the integral of $u$.

So as you can see that if you do not take $-\frac{2}{3}$ out of the integral then you cannot apply the substitution method to evaluate the integral.

Comment: You'll end up with the right answer because you're converting back to $x$ terms at the end, but the limits of integration should really be changed at the intermediate step since you're integrating on $u$.

Comment: @BunsofWrath Yes, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Consider we do a $u$ substitution.

$u=1-3x$

$du=-3dx$

We have $2dx$ but not $-3dx$

How do we get the $-3dx$?

Notice $(\frac{-2}{3})(-3)dx=2dx$

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you do not have to factor the $-2/3$ out of the equation. You could still leave in $-2/3$ and integrate, which would cause you to divide by $-3$ which would give you the same answer.